# Navigation buttons support in browser with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i creating small project to learn JavaScript and PHP. I would like to create AJAX navigation with some subpages without reloading my site. I get HTML code by fetch from internal server, and replace downloaded HTML code with original code in my .php file after click button.

I read a bit on the internet and concluded that i should use the History API, but I do not know how. Many solutions are based on jQuery, but I would not like to use frameworks. Maybe there are other ways to create this navigation?

```
button.addEventListener('click', getDataFromJsonUI);

   function getDataFromJsonUI(){
    fetch("link_to_my_JSON")
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(result){
        output = result[0].html;
        userInterfaceBox.innerHTML = output;

    });
}
```

Event 'click' properly change original html but navigation in browser doesn't work. Only the address in the browser bar changes, and the content of the page is static.

Comment: Your code does not use the history API so it's really hard to imagine what's going on. Anyway, if your url changes und you are not using hashes, e.g. navigating from www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com#page2 a browser refresh (reload) happens so even if you already sent your request fetching the data no valid handler will be there to handle the response.

Comment: one way is to use bookmarks ("#") instead of "?" for query values.  The click would update window.location (same page plus bookmark so no re-load occurs) and you put a listener on the window's "hashchange" event to fire the script... which then reads query values and routes the calls accordingly.  I believe this is a bit out-dated though.  I used to use a plugin called "hashchange" for this.

Comment: Also consider history.pushstate:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: my recipe site uses the old-school hash method (you'll notice the links all get intercepted by script and location updated if you have javascript turned on in your browser...): https://www.recipebookshare.com